# categorical moderator - ordinal iv and ordinal dv

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, spearman-rho, interaction

I have found a significant positive correlation between 2 ordinal variables collected from likert scale data (Creativity at work and Engagement at work).
I used the non parametric Spearmans rho test to calculate this.

I now need to see if this correlation is moderated by generation.
Generation is therefore a categorical moderator with 2 levels (Millenial's/non millenial's).

What test should I use to see if there is a significant difference in the correlation between creativity and engagement for Millenials Vs Non Millenials?

Answer (score 1):

If one of the variables is conceived of as dependent and the other independent, then you can run a regression with two main effects and an interaction.

If not, then you can stratify on the moderate and then test the difference in the two correlations.

Comment: Thanks so much Peter - not too sure what you mean by stratify on the moderate? Does that just mean split my sample into millenials and non millenials? I have done this already, but no idea what test in spss will test the difference in the two correlations? Thanks so much for responding, didn't think I would hear anything back :-)

Comment: Yes. Stratifying means splitting your data.  I don't use SPSS so I don't know how to do that, but it must be possible.